# Is there any way to get opposite of graphql query fields?

Tags: javascript, graphql

I would like to get the opposite GraphQL query field:

which mean the query string will not appeal in the result, while not inside the query string will appeal in the result.

Because there are varties of json recorders, I can not manually write opposite query. Any way to write opposite query automatically?

for example, I have JSON like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "source": "AWS",
    "hero": {
      "version": "my version",
      "name": "R2-D2",
      "friends": [
        {
          "attribute": "like something",
          "name": "Luke Skywalker"
        },
        {
          "name": "Han Solo"
        },
        {
          "name": "Leia Organa"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have query

```
{
  source,
  hero {
    name
    friends {
      attribute
    }
  }
}
```

I like to get a result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "hero": {
      "version": "my version",
      "friends": [
        {
          "name": "Luke Skywalker"
        },
        {
          "name": "Han Solo"
        },
        {
          "name": "Leia Organa"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Which the query fields not in the query will appear in the result, while the query fields in the query will not inside the result.
How to do these operations in JavaScript? Can you give me an example?

Comment: what you are asking for is pretty weird behavior. could you explain a bit more about it? cheers.

Comment: isn't what you asking going against graphql query structure? your query is correct.

Comment: I want do opposite query, I mean I want to get reasult not in the query while the query string will not appealed in the result @David

Comment: Ah you want the properties not in the query? - in that case write another query for the properties not there.

Comment: because there is lots of json records like example, I just want the to delete these properties in the query @David

Comment: Or you can automatically generate query. @David

Comment: GraphQL is about asking for specific fields on objects, you would have to write different queries.

Comment: Can I generate opposite query automatically? @David

Comment: ive updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You only get the fields you include in the Query if you want to get whats not in the query then write another query for the fields not in the original query.

> At its simplest, GraphQL is about asking for specific fields on objects.

https://graphql.org/learn/queries/

**Query:**

```
{
  hero {
    version
    friends {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "hero": {
      "version": "my version",
      "friends": [
        {
          "name": "Luke Skywalker"
        },
        {
          "name": "Han Solo"
        },
        {
          "name": "Leia Organa"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Update from comments:**

Your question is more of how to ***Dynamically Generate GraphQL Queries?***

In this case you could use fragments, but you would still have to write multiple queries.

> Fragments let you construct sets of fields, and then include them in queries where you need to.

https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments